# how to convert user movie ratings into RDF

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I have a data set containing movie ratings by different users. The data set is a tsv file where there are three columns for user, movie and rating. How to convert this data set into rdf format?

Comment: You mean technically or how to model the data as RDF?

Comment: I meant how to model it in the form of triples

Comment: Obviously, you have to model a 3-ary relation which needs some kind of blank node in RDF, e.g.   `:user1 :hasRating [ :forMovie :movie1; :ratingValue 5 . ]`

Comment: could you please explain how this can be done in protege

Comment: Since OWL only has binary individuals, you always need some "dummy" individual which denotes the other relations. In your case, for each user you have to add an relation to some individual which itself has a relation to the film and the value of the rating. Or you could relate each movie to an individual which itself is related to the user and the value of the rating. It's up to you what you prefer.

Comment: I'm new to protege and I'm not able to figure out how to add a relationship as a member of a class.

Comment: That is not what I said. You need an intermediate individual which has e.g. the information about the film and the rating.

Comment: This won't cause redundancy? I will have to create so many individuals for a single movie for storing ratings of that movie by different users.

Comment: One more time: **RDF only allows binary relations** and **you have to model a ternary relation**, thus, there is no other way. For each movie you have to add some rating individual (it can also be an anonymous individual), that relates to the rating value and the other that gave that value.

Comment: okay, got it, thanks

Comment: Ok. Please provide an answer once you finished your solution. And then accept your own answer. This helps other people with similar problems. Cheers.